# How to get local parameter in jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I stuck in a problem.I'm new to jquery. I want to know if this is possible to get variable in jquery scripts. For example I have this Query in my view:

```
 @{  
      string date = ViewBag.Date == null ? null : ViewBag.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");              
  }
            @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
    new { page, creationDate= date,  sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, AccountIdFilter = ViewBag.AccountIdFilter }))
            @section scripts
            {                           

                <script type="text/javascript" >

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        console.log("ready!");
                        $('.initial-value-type-gregorian-example')
                            .persianDatepicker({
                                initialValueType: 'gregorian',
                                toolbox: { submitButton: { enabled: true }},
                            })
                        document.getElementById("DateTime").value = null;
                        var c = document.getElementByName("date").value ;
                        console.log(c);
                    });                                       
                </script>

            }
```

Main part is here: `var c = document.getElementByName("date").value ;`
Is it passible to get the value of this part :  `string date = ViewBag.Date == null ? null : ViewBag.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` I know this  is not true :
`var c = document.getElementByName("date").value ;`
So what should I do?

Comment: can you not just do `var c = '@date'` if you want it to be that date?  Or why not just put that date into input if that's where it's meant to be?

Comment: @Pete Many thanks, I'm new to this sorry for this simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I am not a big fan of mixing Razor and JavaScript code. It pretty much makes it impossible to keep your js code in its own files, so while you could do `let c = '@date'`, I'd suggest to store your model / ViewBag / TempData in a hidden input or `data-foo` attribute on a markup node and query it from your JavaScript code:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
    return View();
}
```

Markup:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Viewbagdate" id="viewbagdate" value="@ViewBag.Date" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var valueFromViewBag = document.getElementById("viewbagdate").value;
```